# War card game in java text based

Tags: java, arrays, text, arraylist

I need some help creating a war card game in java. I'm pretty inexperienced with ArrayLists, and I'm guessing this is what I need to use to add and remove cards from the computer's array of cards and the user's array of cards.

Can anyone give me some help on the steps I should take and the ArrayList methods I can use to print, compare, etc. cards?

Code is welcome, I'm kinda new to this!

Thanks

Comment: @DanW:  To be fair, War was how I learned much of the Python I do today.  Then again, I had read up on a few tutorials beforehand...

Answer (score 2):

1. Consider making some sort of `Card` object that will handle all of the suits and values.
2. Create an `ArrayList<Card>` to hold the cards in.
3. Implement the logic of the game:

   1. Dequeue cards from the front of the ArrayList using `ArrayList.remove(int)`, and enqueue them using `ArrayList.add(Object)`.
   2. Consider what happens during a turn.  Each `Card` must have a weight.
   3. Consider what happens when two cards of equal weight are placed down.  What do you do then?

---

Get these things out of the way.  Code can come later.  Also, check out the Java API for [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html); it will help you a lot.